# Mentioned insertion sort program is not working for the input {5 , 3 , 4 , 2 ,1} but it is working for {5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1} . But Why?

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures, insertion-sort

Following program is able to sort the {5 , 4 , 3 , 2 ,1} but is not able to sort {5 , 3 , 4 , 2 ,1} is ascending order , not able to figure out why this is happening need help regarding the same ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace algoandds
{
    class Program
    {
        public  void  insertsort (int[] arr, int n )
        {
            int value , hole ;

            for  (int i = 1 ; i < n  ;i++ )
            {

                value = arr[i];
                hole = i;
                while(hole > 0 && arr[i-1] > value) /* sorting logic */
                {
                    arr[hole] = arr[hole - 1];
                    hole = hole - 1;
               }
                arr[hole] = value;

            }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[5]{5 , 3 , 4 , 2 ,1};
            Program p1 = new Program();
            p1.insertsort(arr, arr.Length);

            for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake in your nested loop, it should be `arr[hole-1]` (not arr[i-1]) as you need to compare every previous value in the array.

```
 while(hole > 0 && arr[hole-1] > value) /* sorting logic */
```

Check your [`working code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KUHY6s)

Answer (score 0):

Change `while(hole > 0 && arr[i-1] > value)` to `while(hole > 0 && arr[hole-1] > value)`